# Valid signing identity not found

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need help with this error when i create provisioning profile?
I build provisioning for development for test my app on actual device.
Please help me.
thanks...

Answer (score 0):

May be you forgot to add your device UDID in that provision profile ? And Make sure you selected provision profile at target and project level.